# How to determine if one string contains words from another string

Tags: c#

I would like to check whether a string contains words in arbitrary order in C#. How can I do this with a simple if statement. See the example below:

```
string a = "PT. DOWELL ANADRILL SCHLUMBERGER";
string b = "ANADRILL DOWELL";

if( a.Contains( b ) ) {
    MessageBox.Show("true");
} else { 
    // the if always evaluates to false
    MessageBox.Show("false"); 
}
```

Comment: So you want to know if `a` contains any of the words in `b`, or all of the words in `b`, but in any order?

Comment: string.Contains() is searching for any instance of "ANADRILL DOWELL" in your string "a" which is not there, right? That's why it is always false.

Comment: "ANADRILL DOWELL" does not equal "DOWELL ANADRILL".  You would have to split the sentences into word collections and go from there.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know if `a` contains any word in `b` then

```
if(b.Split().Any(x => a.Contains(x)))
```

Or if you want `a` to contain all of the words in `b`

```
if(b.Split().All(x => a.Contains(x)))
```

Note neither make sure the words in `b` are not subwords in `a` like

```
a = "Once before";
b = "be";
```

Also this only splits the words in `b` on whitespace, so it wouldn't work if there is punctuation you want to ignore like

```
a = "I like turtles";
b = "like.";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, if you know there is a space in between each word to check.

```
if(b.Split(' ').Any(a.Contains))
```

Comment: The default for `Split` is whitespace, so the only reason to do that is if you specifically don't want to split on other types of whitespace.  Using the method group instead of a lambda is an acceptable way to shorten code though.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string[] words = names.Split(';', '=', '\n', ' ', '\t');

            String utga = textBox6.Text;
            String utga1 = "IMSI";
            int loop = 0;

            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                int j = i+1;

                if (words[i] == utga)
                {
                    string loop = words[i+1];
                    if(words[j] == utga1)
                    {

                    MySqlDataAdapter adp1 = new MySqlDataAdapter("Insert into hlr.hlr(IMSI,MSISDN_COLUMN) Values('" + loop + "','" + words[i + 1] + "')", connection);
                    DataTable hlr = new DataTable();
                    adp1.Fill(hlr);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = hlr;
                    adp1.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();

                    //i = i + too;

                    i++;

                }

                else
                {
                    i++;

                }
            }
```

}

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks